# How to create a dictionary of string and delegate in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

In C#, I have a dictionary as below:

```
var myActionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>();

myActionDictionary.add("Test1", Test1Method);
```

where it will run a method that takes string as a parameter and returns void when I invoke it.

```
private void Test1Method(string text)
{ return null;}
```

How do I change create a dictionary so that it runs a method and returns a string?

```
var myDelegateDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ???<string>();

myDelegateDictionary.add("Test2", Test2Method);

private string Test2Method(string text)
{ return text;}
```

What do I write for ??? and how do I declare a delegate?
thanks

Comment: That would be with `Func`.

Comment: not Func, it does not take any parameters?

Comment: Yes Func can take parameters, 0-16 of them.

Comment: It would be a `Func<string, string>`. The first generic argument specifies the input parameter type, the last generic argument the output parameter type.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Oliver. and everyone.